# React: Change Style of component after AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, reactjs, styles

I currently creating a dynamic design UI. I'm using an axios call too get the dynamic design properties like background color, font color, images to be displayed.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import MainButton from '../utilities/MainButton';

const tinycolor = require("tinycolor2");
const styles = {
  underlineStyle: {
    borderColor: blue800
  }
}

class MobileHome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);        
    this.color = '';
    this.state = {
      mainColor: '',
      fontColor: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('/getEventConfig').then(res => {
      var config = res.data;
      var color = tinycolor(config.COLOR);
      var font = '#fff';
      if (color.isLight()){
        font = '#000';
      }
      this.color = color;
      this.setState({mainColor: config.COLOR}); // error on timing issue
      console.log('set state', this.state.mainColor);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="center-panel">  

      <TextField
        hintText="Enter Code Here"
        fullWidth={true}
        underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
        id="event_code" />

          <MainButton
            label="Upload Photo"
            fullWidth={true}
            size="xl"
            color={color}
            fontcolor={this.state.fontColor}
            onClick={this.uploadPhoto}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MobileHome
```

On which, my MainButton is another component, just calling the Material UI RaisedButton:

```
class MainButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log('p', this.props);
    let mainColor = _.isNil(this.props.color) ? '#2E65C2': this.props.color;
    let fontColor = _.isNil(this.props.fontColor) ? '#FFF': this.props.fontColor;

    this.styles = {
      root: {
        width: 225
      },
      label: {
        color: fontColor,
        paddingTop: 5
      },
      color: mainColor,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <RaisedButton
      label={this.props.label}
      fullWidth={this.props.fullWidth}
      buttonStyle={this.styles.button}
      style={this.styles.root}
      backgroundColor={this.styles.color}
      labelStyle={this.styles.label}
      onClick={this.props.onClick}
      />
    )
  }
}
export default MainButton;
```

The problem is, the MainButton is rendered already before the axios call is completed. I'm looking for some way, for the render to wait before the axios call to be completed, before it shows the UI. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ternary operator to show MainButton based on state change.
Check below code, here I have taken new state variable resReceived and setting it to false by default. In API res setting to true.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import MainButton from '../utilities/MainButton';

const tinycolor = require("tinycolor2");
const styles = {
  underlineStyle: {
    borderColor: blue800
  }
}

class MobileHome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);        
    this.color = '';
    this.state = {
      mainColor: '',
      fontColor: '',
      resReceived: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('/getEventConfig').then(res => {
      var config = res.data;
      var color = tinycolor(config.COLOR);
      var font = '#fff';
      if (color.isLight()){
        font = '#000';
      }
      this.color = color;
      this.setState({mainColor: config.COLOR, resReceived: true}); // error on timing issue
      console.log('set state', this.state.mainColor);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="center-panel">  

      <TextField
        hintText="Enter Code Here"
        fullWidth={true}
        underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
        id="event_code" />
        {this.state.resReceived ? 
          <MainButton
            label="Upload Photo"
            fullWidth={true}
            size="xl"
            color={color}
            fontcolor={this.state.fontColor}
            onClick={this.uploadPhoto}/>
         : ''}
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MobileHome
```

OR

If you want to keep the button disabled until you receive a response then try below one.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import MainButton from '../utilities/MainButton';

const tinycolor = require("tinycolor2");
const styles = {
  underlineStyle: {
    borderColor: blue800
  }
}

class MobileHome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);        
    this.color = '';
    this.state = {
      mainColor: '',
      fontColor: '',
      disableMainButton: true
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('/getEventConfig').then(res => {
      var config = res.data;
      var color = tinycolor(config.COLOR);
      var font = '#fff';
      if (color.isLight()){
        font = '#000';
      }
      this.color = color;
      this.setState({mainColor: config.COLOR, disableMainButton: false}); // error on timing issue
      console.log('set state', this.state.mainColor);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="center-panel">  

      <TextField
        hintText="Enter Code Here"
        fullWidth={true}
        underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
        id="event_code" /> 
          <MainButton
            label="Upload Photo"
            fullWidth={true}
            size="xl"
            color={color}
            fontcolor={this.state.fontColor}
            onClick={this.uploadPhoto}
            disabled = {this.state.disableMainButton}
            />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MobileHome
```

Comment: Great Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

- Here is the Problem:
  mainColor and fontColor are init in constructor of MainButton.
  constructor can be init only once, so those two dynamic fields can never be dynamic.
- Here is the solution:
  Move the styles to render function so that the colors can be dynamic when data change.
- Tips: check the react doc https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.

```js
render() {

    const { fontColor, mainColor } = this.props;
    const styles = {
      root: {
        width: 225
      },
      label: {
        color: _.isNil(this.props.fontColor) ? '#FFF': fontColor,
        paddingTop: 5
      },
      color: _.isNil(this.props.color) ? '#2E65C2': mainColor,
    }

    return (
      <RaisedButton
      label={this.props.label}
      fullWidth={this.props.fullWidth}
      buttonStyle={styles.button}
      style={styles.root}
      backgroundColor={styles.color}
      labelStyle={styles.label}
      onClick={this.props.onClick}
      />
    )
  }
```